# Perl read and write text file with strings

Tags: perl

Friends need help. Following my INPUT TEXT FILE

```
Andrew   UK
Cindy    China
Rupa     India
Gordon   Australia
Peter    New Zealand
```

To convert the above into hash and to write back into file when the records exist in a directory. I have tried following (it does not work).

```
#!/usr/perl/5.14.1/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();
my $file = ".../input_and_output.txt";
my $people;
my $country;

open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open the file $file: ";
my $line;
while (my $line =<$fh>) {
  my ($people) = split("", $line);
  $hash{$people} = 1;
}


foreach my $people (sort keys %hash) {

  my @country = $people;
  foreach my $c (@country) {
    my $c_folder = `country/test1_testdata/17.26.6/$c/`;   

    if (-d $cad_root){
      print "Exit\n";
    } else {
      print "NA\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: How does it not work? What's happening? What's your intended output? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Is the input file correct? it's got "..." in it which surely isn't valid.

Comment: I've tidied the formatting of your code. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself in future. If you want a large number of strangers to read and understand your code, then surely it makes sense to make it as easy to understand as possible. And thoughtful formatting is one of a programmer's best tools for making code understandable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If what you want is a counter of names in a hash, then I got you, buddy!

I won't attempt the rest of the code because you are checking a folder of records
that I don't have access to so I can't trouble shoot anything more than this.

I see one of your problems. Look at this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;  
use feature 'say'; # Really like using say instead of print because no need for newline. 
        
my $file = 'input_file.txt';
my $fh; # A filehandle. 
        
my %hash;
my $people;
my $country;
my $line;  
unless(open($fh, '<', $file)){die "Could not open file $_ because $!"}
        
while($line = <$fh>)
{
($people, $country) = split(/\s{2,}/, $line); # splitting on at least two spaces
        
say "$people \t $country"; # Just printing out the columns in the file or people and Country.
                
$hash{$people}++; # Just counting all the people in the hash.
                    # Seeing how many unique names there are, like is there more than one Cindy, etc ...?     
}
            
say "\nNow I'm just sorting the hash of people by names.";

foreach(sort{$a cmp $b} keys %hash)
{
say "$_ => $hash{$_}"; # Based on your file. The counter is at 1 because nobody has the same names. 
}
```

Here is the output. As you can see I fixed the problem by splitting on at least two white-spaces so the country names don't get cut out.

```
Andrew   UK

Cindy    China

Rupa     India

Gordon   Australia

Peter    New Zealand

Andrew   United States

Now I'm just sorting the hash of people by names.
Andrew => 2
Cindy => 1
Gordon => 1
Peter => 1
Rupa => 1
```

I added another Andrew to the file. This Andrew is from the United States
as you can see. I see one of your problems. Look at this:

```
my ($people) = split("", $line);
```

You are splitting on characters as there is no space between those quotes.
If you look at this change now, you are splitting on at least one space.

```
 my ($people) = split(" ", $line);
```

Comment: I just realized that there is a problem with this.
Peter is from New Zealand, but  the country just shows New because we splitted on one or more white-spaces, and there is one whites-space separating New Zealand and also my United States so I should make this so that we separated on at least 2 whitespaces on the split, or you could separate the columns of people and countries with commas and that would be better and then we split on the comma.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [the documentation for `split()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and look closely at the optional third argument it takes. Sinan is making use of it in his answer.

Comment: Is your `unless (open(...)) { ... }` deliberately designed to confuse people? What's wrong with the standard `open ... or ...` that Perl programmers (including the original poster) have been using for decades?

Comment: No, it's not designed to confuse people. What's wrong with it? Also, what's with the dislike, bro? I produced the desired output.

Comment: Sinan, didn't even build a hash like the asker requested, and yet he gets more respect for doing less work?

Comment: It's not dislike "bro", it's constructive criticism. Sinan is someone who understands the language and knows how to work with the syntax. You're clearly fighting against the language in exactly the same way as the original poster :-)

Comment: I know how the language works. If I didn't my code would obviously not produce the desired output ... but it does.

Comment: If you're posting advice on a site like this, I always think it's worth going the extra mile to produce easy-to-follow code that shows the language in the best light. I'm not sure you agree with that aim.

Comment: Look at your code. The indentation is all over the place. You're loading modules that you don't use. You're declaring variables outside the scope where they are used. It's not just about getting the job done. It's about showing people best practices. And that's not what you're doing.

Comment: It is generally a futile task, *birader*, to try to guess at the actual solution the OP is imagining when there is no solid description of the problem to go on. However, I added a couple of possible variations to my answer. My advice to you: "*Don't worry about how many upvotes others are getting. Focus on improving yourself.*"

Comment: *"I produced the desired output"*  Producing the desired output is only the very tiniest part of writing good software. Your effort is atrocious by almost all other measures. And **Dave Cross** isn't your "bro".

Comment: And what defines good code? Small programs, Readable Programs, or fast programs? You can't really have all at the same time. A simple program could be solved with object oriented code which is good practice for longer projects, but do you really need to do that when it's not neccessary? Sure a problem can be solved 100 ways, but if you solve it the same way everytime which is the most popular method, then you don't really know the ins, and outs of your language. No one always greets everyone with "Hi". Sometimes we say "Hello". Why can't we have variety in our programs, too?

Comment: Plus, Perl's motto is that there is more than one way to do it. But you say we should always do it your way which means that you disagree with Larry Wall, the creator of your language. Why would he make Perl so adept at solving problems differently if we aren't supposed to try the other methods that he created? I guess every facet of the language is a mistake then.

Answer (score 3):

This is the primary problem:

```
my ($people) = split("", $line);
```

Your are splitting using an empty string, and you are assigning the return value to a single variable (which will just end up with the first character of each line).

Instead, you should `split` on `' '` (a single space character which is [a special pattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)):

> As another special case, ... when the PATTERN is either omitted or a string composed of a single space character (such as `' '` or `"\x20"` , but not e.g. `/ /`). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were `/\s+/`; in particular, this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.

Limit the number of fields returned to ensure the integrity of country names with spaces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @people;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ /\S/ or next;
    $line =~ s/\s+\z//;
    push @people, [ split ' ', $line, 2 ];
}

use YAML::XS;
print Dump \@people;

__DATA__
Andrew   UK
Cindy    China
Rupa     India
Gordon   Australia
Peter    New Zealand
```

The entries are added to an array so 1) The input order is preserved; and 2) Two people with the same name but from different countries do not result in one entry being lost.

If the order is not important, you could just use a hash keyed on country names with people's names in an array reference for each entry. For now, I am going to assume order matters (it would help us help you if you put more effort into formulate a clear question).

One option is to now go through the list of person-country pairs, and print all those pairs for which the directory `country/test1_testdata/17.26.6/$c/` exists (incidentally, in your code you have

> ```
> my $c_folder = `country/test1_testdata/17.26.6/$c/`;
> ```

That will try to execute a program called `country/test1_testdata/17.26.6/$c/` and save its output in `$c_folder` if it produces any. To moral of the story: In programming, precision matters. Just because `` ` `` looks like `'`, that doesn't mean you can use one to mean the other.)

Given that your question is focused on hashes, I use an array of references to anonymous hashes to store the list of people-country pairs in the code below. I cache the result of the lookup to reduce the number of times you need to hit the disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 2 ? run( @ARGV )
      : die_usage()
;

sub run {
    my $people_data_file = shift;
    my $country_files_location = shift;

    open my $in, '<', $people_data_file
        or die "Failed to open '$people_data_file': $!";

    my @people;
    my %countries;

    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        next unless $line =~ /\S/; # ignore lines consisting of blanks
        $line =~ s/\s+\z//;# remove all trailing whitespace
        my ($name, $country) = split ' ', $line, 2;
        push @people, { name => $name, country => $country };
        $countries{ $country } = undef;
    }

    # At this point, @people has a list of person-country pairs
    # We are going to use %countries to reduce the number of
    # times we need to check the existence of a given directory,
    # assuming that the directory tree is stable while this program
    # is running.

    PEOPLE:
    for my $person ( @people ) {
        my $country = $person->{country};
        if ($countries{ $country }) {
            print join("\t", $person->{name}, $country), "\n";
        }
        elsif (-d "$country_files_location/$country/") {
            $countries{ $country } = 1;
            redo PEOPLE;
        }
    }
}

sub die_usage {
    die "Need data file name and country files location\n";
}
```

Now, there are a bazillion variations on this which is why it is important for ***you*** to formulate a clear and concise question so people trying to help you can answer ***your*** specific questions, instead of each coming up his/her own solution to the problem as they see it. For example, one could also do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 2 ? run( @ARGV )
      : die_usage()
;

sub run {
    my $people_data_file = shift;
    my $country_files_location = shift;

    open my $in, '<', $people_data_file
        or die "Failed to open '$people_data_file': $!";

    my %countries;

    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        next unless $line =~ /\S/; # ignore lines consisting of blanks
        $line =~ s/\s+\z//;# remove all trailing whitespace
        my ($name, $country) = split ' ', $line, 2;
        push @{ $countries{$country} }, $name;
    }

    for my $country (keys %countries) {
        -d "$country_files_location/$country"
            or delete $countries{ $country };
    }

    # At this point, %countries maps each country for which
    # we have a data file to a list of people. We can then
    # print those quite simply so long as we don't care about
    # replicating the original order of lines from the original
    # data file. People's names will still be sorted in order
    # of appearance in the original data file for each country.

    while (my ($country, $people) = each %countries) {
        for my $person ( @$people) {
            print join("\t", $person, $country), "\n";
        }
    }
}


sub die_usage {
    die "Need data file name and country files location\n";
}
```

Comment: `split ' '` is strictly speaking not necessary, but it saves a lot of headaches in case there is a stray leading space somewhere. And, with data files that might move between Windows and Unixy systems, `s/\s+\z//` rather than `chomp` saves more headaches -- unless, of course, there is a spec that says trailing whitespace is significant.